# How to detect if English localizable.strings is being used?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

In my app, I want to be able to detect when the user is using my English version of `localizable.strings`. Is the best way to do this simply to put a flag in the English version of `localizable.strings` and check if its value is "YES" ? For instance:

```
/* Key which determines if the language is English */
"EnglishKey" = "YES";
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to have a "current language" string that translates as "English" (or whatever language is being used).

Comment: @HotLicks - Yeah you're right that would probably make more sense in case I ever need to check specifically if it's some other language that isn't english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is the only way that I've really found - putting a string in localizable.strings which identifies language and then reading that in. Kind of surprising to me there isn't another way to find out, but I'll mark this as yes for now until something better comes along.

Answer (score 0):

see [NSLocale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.  Its a Foundation class that encapsulates all of the conventions about  language and culture for a particular locale.

These two methods might be of use:
[[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];   // display name of a locale identifier

[NSLocale preferredLanguages];  // returns an array of language identifier strings, in order of user preference.

Here a brief write up of how [NSLocale works](http://nshipster.com/nslocale/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah the problem with preferred language is if I ask if its english and it says no, it doesn't necessarily mean that my app hasn't used the english localizable.strings (if the user has some obscure preferred language like Thai and I don't have a localization for it, it will automatically go to English, but preferredLanguages won't tell me that).

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider users preferred Language should be at the top of the list.

Comment: Right but if it's not English, the English localizable.strings could still be used, and then I won't know.